# jQuery validation are not working in common file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').validate({
            rules: {
                    fname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                lname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
            phone: {
                    phoneUS: true,
                    required: true
            },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
    <input class="email" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile Number">
    <input class="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

I have created a file name footer.php and include this file in all pages of my website inside footer.php file I have created a simple form and want to validate with jquery but validation are not working in common file however, If I run same code on jsfiddle it works perfectly. So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: One thing you can do is add an id or class to the submit button. In js make a click function refering to that class or id and set it to prefentDefault. This way you make sure that your form isn't posted directly

Comment: Is it compulsory @SuperDJ

Comment: Are there any JS-errors in your browser-console? I recommend monitoring this at first! Do you get any errors?

Comment: You haven't included jquery.validate.js in the page...?

Comment: @SuperDJ you ccan just use `debug: true` within the validate plugin options to do the same thing in a much easier way

Comment: I have include jquery.validate.js but its now working right now @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Make sure you have jquery file loaded in each page head tag.

Answer (score -1):

Everything seems to be fine for me but i cannot find jquery validation plugin.make sure you add this plugin after jquery script.

Comment: 'It's working for me' isn't an answer, as the OP clearly has some issue. If you need more information, add it in a comment - assuming someone hasn't already done so